# Why Telegram bot stop working after a while, Netlify problem?

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, netlify

I have programmed a very basic Telegram bot and I'm having a problem.

As soon as I deploy it works correctly, but after a while why it stops working and I have to enter the following site (https://pruebabot.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/hello) to get it back to work.

I have set the webhook as follows:
https://api.telegram.org/botBOTTOKEN/setWebhook?url=https://pruebabot.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/hello

The bot's github repository can be found here: https://github.com/antoniocuadros2/telegramBotPrueba

I can't understand why this is happening.

Here the code:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.TELEGRAMBOTTOKEN);

bot.start(ctx =>{
    ctx.reply("Bienvenido, soy @asignaturasivbot, ¿en qué puedo ayudarte?, puedo hacer todo lo que está en /help");
})

bot.help(ctx =>{
    ctx.reply("Ayudaaaaaaaaaaaa");
})

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
    try{
        await bot.handleUpdate(JSON.parse(event.body));
        return { statusCode: 200, body: ''};
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e)
        return { statusCode: 400, body: 'Está siendo utilizado por un bot de telegram: @asignaturasivbot'};
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, please provide code samples that we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: I just added code samples

Comment: Have you checked the logs on your deployment platform? Are there any errors? Is this a free or paid platform? Free tier of deployment platforms have limitations and it might limit incoming HTTP requests.